# Identifying the capacitor polarity from a Samsung 2333SW LCD Monitor

Tags: capacitor, polarity

There are no marks on the sides or the bottom, Only the top is marked by a half moon.(See Picture) How do I determine the negative side of the capacitor.[image] wires on the bottom come from the half moon side and opposite of the half moon

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: I Don't have the data sheet

Answer (score 2):

The black marking is typically the negative lead.